# passing a JSON object from JavaScript to Android

Tags: javascript, android, json, code-injection

My application so far records a number of functions that are performed in a web view and stores them into variables. This has been done using JavaScript that I have injected it into my Android Application. So far I have used the JSON stringify function to create a JSONObject as shown.

```
var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(chars);
```

My Question is how do I get the `myJSONText` Variable from the JavaScript to Java so I can fiddle with it there. I have tired to look for how to do this but have not had any luck. Any help or links would be appreciated.

Comment: Your data needs to be submitted to the Java application. This can be done by using Ajax.

Comment: Can't I use the JavaScriptInterface? I wouldn't know where to start with ajax as I haven't used it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a JavascriptInterface to your webview with:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavascriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Let the JavacriptInterface have a method like:

```
public void receiveJSON(String json);
```

Call this method in javascript with:

```
document.write(window.HTMLOUT.receiveJSON(myJSONText));
```

Comment: What do I need to put in the java method?

Comment: You mean in receiveJSON? Thats where you get your JSON from javascript, so you can start fiddling around as you wished.

Comment: LOL. Start fiddling around! 

Comment: I have tried creating the receive JSON method and put the follwing in.         public void receiveJSON(String myJSONText) throws JSONException {
   
         JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(myJSONText);  
         Convert = myObject.toString();
         Log.i(TAG, "testinggggg");

        
        }
the problem is I cant call the method without it causing an error could could help me with this please.